# Issues with vlcj.jar at run

Tags: java, netbeans-8, vlcj

I'm testing vlcj for the first time, following [this tutorial](http://mrbool.com/api-vlcj-creating-java-audio-video-players/33033), but when I run it I get this error-output:

```
cd C:\Users\abolfazl\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testplayer; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_05" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.testplayer.InformationLib\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_05\\bin\\java.exe\" -DnetbeansProjectMappings= -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building mrbool.vlc.example 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.pom

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.939s
Finished at: Thu Sep 08 13:49:28 IRDT 2016
Final Memory: 6M/159M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal on project mrbool.vlc.example: Could not resolve dependencies for project mrbool.vlc:mrbool.vlc.example:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [uk.co.caprica:vlcj:jar:3.10.1 (compile), org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

My InformationLib.java is:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.x.LibXUtil;

public class InformationLib {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("aaaaaa");
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
                RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "d:/vlc-2.2.1");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        LibXUtil.initialise();       

        System.out.println("  version: {}" + LibVlc.INSTANCE.libvlc_get_version());
        System.out.println(" compiler: {}" + LibVlc.INSTANCE.libvlc_get_compiler());
        System.out.println("changeset: {}" + LibVlc.INSTANCE.libvlc_get_changeset());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your machine is not able to resolve the hostname `repo.maven.apache.org` and that is the cause for the fail. The hostname resolves fine here and the maven repository is found. So I assume this is some problem with your local DNS.